# node js real time chat read or not read status

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Actually I have to implement read and not read status in simple node chat with `socket.io`.

I have already build real time chat application with help of node and `socket.io`.
But now what I want is when **user1** send message to another **user2**. **user1** has status of if **user2** read or not read message which is send to another user like whatsup do right now.

any idea about this status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a draw and send application using Nodejs and Socket.io , Here is my app's repository: https://github.com/mg52/DrawChat. The application has sent/sending (it works like read/not read) status. In my app every users have an unique id. This sent/sending status depends on these unique ids.

For example,

in index.html:

when you click on send button,

```
message_sent.innerHTML = "Message Send Status: Sending..."

socket.on("get_message", function (data) {
//getting message from sender (from index.js)
socket.emit("message_sent",{sentuserid:data.userid});

});
```

in index.js:

```
socket.on("message_sent", function(data){
    io.sockets.emit("message_sent_correctly",{msc:data.sentuserid});
    //it sends back to all users (includes sender) the sender's id 
});
```

in index.html:

```
socket.on("message_sent_correctly",function(data){
    socket.emit("check_id", {ci: data.msc});
    //sends back to server to control who has sent the message
});
```

in index.js:

```
socket.on("check_id",function(data){
    if(data.ci === user.uid){
        socket.emit("id_checked");
    }
    //if id equals to sender's id returns to index.html that the message has been sent successfully
});
```

in index.html:

```
socket.on("id_checked",function(){
     message_sent.innerHTML = "Your message has been read!";
    });
```

I know that this codes may not be the shortest way to hande read/not read status. But it works perfect.

Comment: mg52 Thanks for helpful script!
This is the status that sender will get the status that message has been sent to receiver successfully.
I am wandering about how do I know the status that sender sent message has been read by receiver or not?